# How to ROS messages via bluetooth? (arduino)

Tags: ros, serial, bluetooth, encoder, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, maybe this could be a novice question:

As the title suggests, i would like to know if it's possible to do that.

Specifically, my aim is to send messages from an **arduino** to the master computer via bluetooth, as i want to build the typical object avoiding robot, but sending custom messages (encoder's data, distance to an object,...) via bluetooth instead of doing it via serial (USB) to that master.

Maybe i could use a BLE module like the HM-06 to do that, but i'm not sure (with the laptops own bluetooth as a receiver?).
Maybe there's a bluetooth methodology that i don't know.

As you see, i am a little bit lost.

I would appreciate a detailed answer (if it's possible) of the steps to do.

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228869/how-to-ros-messages-via-bluetooth?-(arduino)/) by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2016-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simplest solution might be to use Bluez. Check the website : https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/ . This documents the library well and provides source codes in C and Python. In my opinion writing a Python node that listens to the raw data and publishes as ROS topics is a fairly quick solution. I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [ozsln](https://answers.ros.org/users/26252/ozsln/) with karma: 26 on 2016-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on 2016-03-17**:
Hi ozsln!
Thanks for the reply. I'm going to solve temporarily the problem with two arduino UNO and two BT BLE HM-06 modules, sending the data the one on the robot to the one that is connected directly to the computer, running as a data receiver.

I guess using BlueZ could work also.